# Can R be used to send data to BigQuery pragmatically?

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am able to fetch data from Google Analytics using R. But struggling to send data to BigQuery. 
Is there any way we can send and save data to BigQuery using R.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to show a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You can also read [ask].

Comment: [dplyr has a backend.](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/databases.html)